# Can't dynamically add views "child has a parent" android

Tags: java, android, sql, dynamically-generated

Hi guys I'm trying to make this app generate many views based on existing database and xml files.My app is crushing and Im  getting error like `"java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{hovi.akapbox/hovi.akapbox.CytatyActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first."`

Here is code:
-CytatyActivity.java:

```
public class CytatyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cytaty);
    SqlLiteDataBaseHelper sqlLiteDataBaseHelper = new SqlLiteDataBaseHelper(this);

    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_cytaty);
    try {

        if(sqlLiteDataBaseHelper.checkDataBase()){

            Log.e("db: ","Data Base Already Exists");

        }else {

            sqlLiteDataBaseHelper.CopyDataBaseFromAsset();

        }

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {

        sqlLiteDataBaseHelper.openDataBase();
        // after open data  base u can read write data base

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    LayoutInflater factory = getLayoutInflater();
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    View v = factory.inflate(R.layout.layout_cytaty_text, relativeLayout,false);
    View v2 = factory.inflate(R.layout.layout_cytaty_image, relativeLayout ,false);

    Cursor cursor = sqlLiteDataBaseHelper.db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Cytaty",null);
    Context cont = getApplicationContext();

    if( cursor.moveToFirst()) {


        do {

            // fill in any details dynamically here
            TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.TV_cytat);
            textView.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("text")).toString());


            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v2.findViewById(R.id.IV_cytat);
            Log.v("XD","XDDD");
            int id = (int)cont.getResources().getIdentifier(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("imagescr")).toString(), "drawable", cont.getPackageName());
            imageView.setImageResource(id);


            relativeLayout.addView(textView);
            relativeLayout.addView(imageView);

            ll.addView(relativeLayout, 0, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

}
```

}

-layout_cytaty_image.xml:

Any ideas what to do?
I've tryied to add sth like:

```
((ViewGroup)imageView.getParent()).removeView(imageView);
```

but it didnt work. I got error that im using remoteView() on blank argument.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do like this:

```
do {
    // fill in any details dynamically here
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    View v = factory.inflate(R.layout.layout_cytaty_text, null, false);
    View v2 = factory.inflate(R.layout.layout_cytaty_image, null, false);

    TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.TV_cytat);
    textView.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("text")).toString());

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v2.findViewById(R.id.IV_cytat);
    Log.v("XD","XDDD");
    int id = (int)cont.getResources().getIdentifier(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("imagescr")).toString(), "drawable", cont.getPackageName());
    imageView.setImageResource(id);


    relativeLayout.addView(v);
    relativeLayout.addView(v2);

    ll.addView(relativeLayout, 0, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
}
```

But it will be much better if you will create views programmaticaly instead of inflating. Something like this:

```
do {
    TextView textView = new TextView(context);
    //set relative layout params to textView 
    textView.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("text")).toString());

    ImageView imageView = new ImageView (context);
    //set relative layout params to imageView 
    int id = (int)cont.getResources().getIdentifier(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("imagescr")).toString(), "drawable", cont.getPackageName());
    imageView.setImageResource(id);

    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    //set linear layout params to relativeLayout 
    relativeLayout.addView(textView);
    relativeLayout.addView(imageView);

    ll.addView(relativeLayout);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the reply.I managed to have done that programically and im still getting some errors. Here is my new code:

```
public class CytatyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cytaty);
    SqlLiteDataBaseHelper sqlLiteDataBaseHelper = new SqlLiteDataBaseHelper(this);

    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_cytaty);
    try {

        if(sqlLiteDataBaseHelper.checkDataBase()){

            Log.e("db: ","Data Base Already Exists");

        }else {

            sqlLiteDataBaseHelper.CopyDataBaseFromAsset();

        }

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {

        sqlLiteDataBaseHelper.openDataBase();
        // after open data  base u can read write data base

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    LayoutInflater factory = getLayoutInflater();

    Cursor cursor = sqlLiteDataBaseHelper.db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Cytaty",null);
    Context cont = getApplicationContext();

    if( cursor.moveToFirst()) {


        do {
            TextView textView = new TextView(this);
            //set relative layout params to textView
            textView.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("text")).toString());
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            );

            textView.setPadding(15,15,5,10);
            textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
            textView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
            params.setMargins(87, 20, 10, 0);
            textView.setLayoutParams(params);

            ImageView imageView = new ImageView (this);
            //set relative layout params to imageView
            int id = (int)cont.getResources().getIdentifier(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("imagescr")).toString(), "drawable", cont.getPackageName());
            imageView.setImageResource(id);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramv = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)imageView.getLayoutParams();
            paramv.width = 80;
            paramv.height = 80;
            paramv.setMargins(7,20,0,0);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(paramv);

            RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
            //set linear layout params to relativeLayout
            relativeLayout.addView(textView,new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            relativeLayout.addView(imageView);

            ll.addView(relativeLayout);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

}
```

}

Im getting error from line "paramv.width = 80;" and it's throwing that im calling method on empty object.

Comment: When you create view programmaticaly, the view do not have LayoutParams. You need to initialize new layout params and set it to imageView.